# How to fix the Qtab and create more button and text line in the tab area

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

Why my Address `QLabel` not fix in `tab1`

How to fix the `QLabel` in the `tab1`

Why the `button` is fix width

I wall to create different tab have different button or table or text line

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
import os, sys, subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget): 
def __init__(self): 
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self) 

    self.setGeometry(0,0, 900,600) 
    self.setWindowTitle("GUI") 

    tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget() 
    tab1 = QtGui.QWidget() 
    tab2 = QtGui.QWidget() 
    tab3 = QtGui.QWidget()

    p1_vertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab1) 
    p2_vertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab2) 
    p3_vertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab3)

    tab_widget.addTab(tab1, "tab1") 
    tab_widget.addTab(tab2, "tab2") 
    tab_widget.addTab(tab3, "tab3")

    button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("button1") 
    p1_vertical.addWidget(button1)
    button2 = QtGui.QPushButton("button2")
    p1_vertical.addWidget(button2)
    button3 = QtGui.QPushButton("button3")
    p1_vertical.addWidget(button3)
    button4 = QtGui.QPushButton("button4")
    p1_vertical.addWidget(button4)
    button3.move(50,100)
    button3.resize(50,50)

    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout() 
    #vbox.addWidget(menu_bar) 
    vbox.addWidget(tab_widget) 

    self.setLayout(vbox)

    label1 = QtGui.QLabel("Address", self)
    label1.move(20,70)
    edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    edit.setDragEnabled(True)
    edit.move(20,95)
    edit.resize(150,30)
```

Comment: Could you please explain yourself a bit better? What do you mean by "fix"? Fixed position? Fixed size?

Comment: I hope the qlineedit fixed position and the button can fixed size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look into `QtGui.QGridLayout` (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html). This lets you easily align widgets and layouts on a grid and also specify the size of each column.

In your case this would be something like:

```
# Create Layout
self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

# Add widgets    
self.grid.addWidget(label1,1,1)
self.grid.addWidget(edit,2,1)
```

If you want a column have a certain width, you can use

```
self.grid.setColumnMinimumWidth(rowIndex,width)
self.grid.setColumnStretch(rowIndex,stretchFactor)
```

`stretchFactor=1` will cause the row to not be stretched in case of an `resizeEvent`.

If you only want to set the size of a particular `QWidget`, you can use

```
widget.setMaximumSize(width,height)
widget.setMinimumSize(width,height)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i have other question. I hope you can ask me.please!!